# Applying a relative size which includes margins

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` whose `width` is `100%`. I know I can use `box-sizing` (or `-moz-box-sizing`) set to `border-box` to get that `div`'s total width, including borders and padding (but not margin) to be that computed 100%. Is there a way to include the margin in that relative size computation as well?

Alternately, it would be great if there was a **non-Javascript** way to specify a combination of relative and absolute dimensions in a width, e.g.:

```
#my-div {
    width: 100% - 10px;
}
```

Can either of these be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help to know what's your point, but knowing this all - I advice you to use wrapper `div` having width and padding or just having width and `my-div` having margin:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="my-div">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#wrapper { width: 450px; padding: 25px; } /* i.e. relative 100% = 450px now */
  #my-div { margin: 20px; } /* there. now we have 100% - 40px width :] */
```

Something like that?

Comment: I would like my div to fill the entire window, except for small left and right margins, regardless of the window size.

Comment: All that needed to work was to add to the wrapper's CSS: `box-sizing: border-box` so that it would include the padding's width. And my inner div ("`#my-div`") needs the `width: 100%` property because it has `display: table` (which is needed for *its* children... don't ask). Thanks!

Comment: :D I don't like `box-sizing` and `display: table` for their rather *f**cked up* support.

Answer (score 0):

Adam answered the question. My only addition is that you should never need to set a <div/>'s width to 100%. You get that for free, and setting it only creates problems for you.